# How to show in front End images using Visual Composer attach_images?

Tags: plugins, shortcode

```
$gallery = 
  shortcode_atts( array(
       'post_gallery'      =>  'Gallery',
   ), $atts );

$img = wp_get_attachment_image_src($gallery["post_gallery"], "large");

$output = "{$img[3]}";
```

I can't get all the Image URL. It only return 3 Images with index 0, 1 and 2.

How to get all the images that i'm trying to make gallery.

Answer (score 0):

```
$gallery = shortcode_atts( 
                    array(
                        'post_gallery'      =>  'post_gallery',
                    ), $atts );

        $image_ids=explode(',',$gallery['post_gallery']);
        $sigle_img = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_ids[0], "large");
        $img="<div id='tourGallery'><img class='imgthumb' id='' src='".$sigle_img[0]."' style='width:100%' alt=''></div><div id='galleryThumbs'>";
        for($i=0;$i<=9;$i++)
        {
         if($image_ids[$i]!="")
          {
          $imgs = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_ids[$i], "large"); 
          $img.="<div><img class='imgthumb' id='' src='".$imgs[0]."' style='width:100%' alt=''></div>";
          }
        }
        $img.="</div></div>";
        return $img;
```

Achieved!!!